# VB.net linq group-by con múltiples columnas

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, linq

buen dia querida comunidad.

me acerco a ustedes por que no encuentro la solucion.

les platico un poco.

busco crear un group-by con múltiples columnas de agrupado, asi esta mi codigo

```
_listproductionOrderGPListAGP = (From entry In _listproductionOrderGPList
                                                 Group entry By gByKey =
                                                 New With {entry.Line_Id, entry.Line_Name,
                                                           entry.Product_Id, entry.Product_Part_Number, entry.Product_Name, entry.Shift_Id, entry.ShiftDate}
                                                 Into g = Group
                                                 Select New ProductionLineRelationSinOPGP With {
                                                            .Product_Id = g.First().Product_Id,
                                                            .Product_Part_Number = g.First().Product_Part_Number,
                                                            .Product_Name = g.First().Product_Name,
                                                            .Line_Id = g.First().Line_Id,
                                                            .Line_Name = g.First().Line_Name,
                                                            .Shift_Id = g.First().Shift_Id,
                                                            .ShiftDate = g.First().ShiftDate,
                                                            .OK = g.Sum(Function(z) z.OK),
                                                            .NG = g.Count(Function(a) a.OK) - g.Sum(Function(b) b.OK),
                                                            .Total = g.Count(Function(c) c.OK)
                                                          }).ToList()
```

Sin embargo no me agrupa la información me la sigue mostrando sin agrupación les muestro una imagen de los datos que contiene la lista.

[image: Datos]

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.
¡Saludso!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que quiere decir no me agrupa?

Comment: No me agrupa la informacion como la requiero.

Comment: Y como podriamos saber como la queres, y como esta saliendo ahora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buena tarde comunidad despues de mucho buscar di con la repsuesta.

```
_listproductionOrderGPListAGP = (From entry In _listproductionOrderGPList
                                             Group entry By gByKey = New With
                                             {
                                               Key entry.Line_Id, Key entry.Line_Name,
                                               Key entry.Product_Id, Key entry.Product_Part_Number, Key entry.Product_Name,
                                               Key entry.Shift_Id, Key entry.ShiftDate
                                             }
                                             Into gcs = Group
                                             Select New ProductionLineRelationSinOPGP With {
                                                        .Line_Id = gcs.First().Line_Id,
                                                        .Line_Name = gcs.First.Line_Name,
                                                        .Product_Id = gcs.First().Product_Id,
                                                        .Product_Part_Number = gcs.First().Product_Part_Number,
                                                        .Product_Name = gcs.First().Product_Name,
                                                        .Shift_Id = gcs.First().Shift_Id,
                                                        .ShiftDate = gcs.First().ShiftDate,
                                                        .OK = gcs.Sum(Function(z) z.OK),
                                                        .NG = gcs.Count(Function(a) a.OK) - gcs.Sum(Function(b) b.OK),
                                                        .Total = gcs.Count(Function(c) c.OK)
                                                      }).ToList()
```

Lo que me falto es poner la palabra Key a todos los agrupadores..
¡Saludos!